# Inverse mapping (affine transformation) for singular transform matrix

Tags: image-processing

I was reading DIP by *Gonzalez et al*, and came across the concept of getting output image pixel values by calculating nearest neighbour in input image by inverse mapping of output pixel coordinates $(x,y)$ to input coordinates $(v,w)$ and applying its value. Something like

$$
(v,w) = T^{-1} (x,y)
$$
where $T$ is the image transform matrix.

But what if the matrix T is singular. How will we define the nearest neighbour pixels then?
For eg. for

$$
T = \left [
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 &1 &0\\
1 &1 &0\\
0 &0 &1 \end{array}
\right],
$$ whose inverse doesn't exist.

(I am guessing that the transform matrix is changed by adding or subtracting some values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when an inverse is required but the matrix you are taking the inverse of is not guaranteed to be invertible, then the ([Moore-Penrose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse)) [pseudoinverse](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pseudoinverse.html) is used:

In R, if $T$ is

```
T
        [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    0
[2,]    1    1    0
[3,]    0    0    1
```

Then the pseudoinverse calculated using `ginv` is

```
ginv(T)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 0.25 0.25    0
[2,] 0.25 0.25    0
[3,] 0.00 0.00    1
```

Clearly, this won't give the identity matrix when multiplying $T$, but it's as close as you can get with $T$ singular.

```
T*ginv(T)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 0.25 0.25    0
[2,] 0.25 0.25    0
[3,] 0.00 0.00    1
```

Comment: If the only option is to not do the mapping, yes.  Sometimes other regularization constraints are placed on the mapping which forces $T$ to be non-singular.

Comment: There exist there different generalized inverses for different purposes, and the term generalized inverse is sometimes used (hence `ginv`) for pseudo inverses. The book [Generalized Inverses: Theory and Applications](http://mathscinet.ru/files/BenIsraelA-GrevilleT.pdf) provides an extensive background.

Comment: @LaurentDuval Do you mean where does it come from? `library(MASS)`

Comment: My mistake, the comment is now complete